# How to update column value is null using mapping table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have CustomData Table value like this

```
+----------+----------+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| Column_1 | Column_2 |  Column_3   |    Column_4    |      Column_5      |                   |
+----------+----------+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|        1 | Name     | CompanyName | CompanyAddress | CompanyPhoneNumber | CompanyDepartment |
+----------+----------+-------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

and mapping table is

```
+----+----------------+------------------+------------+
| ID |   FieldName    |    DataValue     | ColumnName |
+----+----------------+------------------+------------+
|  1 | CompanyPhone   | 0515784          | Column_1   |
|  2 | CompanyAddress | USATaxes         | Column_2   |
|  4 | CompanyName    | Software         | Column_4   |
|  5 | Email          | HR@telesquad.com | Column_5   |
+----+----------------+------------------+------------+
```

In mapping table column_3 doesn't exist and I want to update custom data column_3 value set to NULL.

How can we do that this task. Anyone help me out please?

Comment: You can only achieve this with Dynamic SQL. Truthfully such a requirement suggests you have a design flaw and should be rethinking the design; a design should not mandate dynamic SQL as a requirement to fulfil such tasks.

Comment: I'm confused.  Maybe I'm not the only one.

Answer (score 1):

While the following answer does not handle the updating of Column_3 to NULL, it does show how you could pull a resultset between CustomData/Mapping that may be easier to use rather than writing dynamic SQL. Unfortunately, I don't understand your data structure or request well enough to know what your real need is.

```
/* Mock-up tables and data */

DECLARE @CustomData table (
    Column_1 int, Column_2 varchar(50), Column_3 varchar(50), Column_4 varchar(50), Column_5 varchar(50)
);

DECLARE @Mapping table (
    ID int, FieldName varchar(50), DataValue varchar(50), ColumnName varchar(50) 
);

INSERT INTO @CustomData VALUES 
    ( 1, 'Name', 'CompanyName', 'CompanyAddress', 'CompanyPhoneNumber' );

INSERT INTO @Mapping VALUES
    ( 1, 'CompanyPhone', '0515784', 'Column_1' ),
    ( 2, 'CompanyAddress', 'USATaxes', 'Column_2' ),
    ( 4, 'CompanyName', 'Software', 'Column_4' ),
    ( 5, 'Email', 'HR@telesquad.com', 'Column_5' );

/* Fetch a resultset between CustomData and Mapping via column names */

SELECT
    d.c.value( 'fn:local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)' ) AS CustomDataColumn,
    d.c.value( '.', 'varchar(50)' ) AS CustomDataValue,
    Map.FieldName AS MappingFieldName
FROM (
    SELECT CAST( ( SELECT * FROM @CustomData FOR XML PATH ( 'column' ), ROOT ( 'data' ) ) AS xml ) AS DataXml
) AS CustData
CROSS APPLY CustData.DataXml.nodes( '//data/column/*' ) d( c )
LEFT JOIN @Mapping AS Map
    ON d.c.value( 'fn:local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)' ) = Map.ColumnName;
```

Returns

```
+------------------+--------------------+------------------+
| CustomDataColumn |  CustomDataValue   | MappingFieldName |
+------------------+--------------------+------------------+
| Column_1         | 1                  | CompanyPhone     |
| Column_2         | Name               | CompanyAddress   |
| Column_3         | CompanyName        | NULL             |
| Column_4         | CompanyAddress     | CompanyName      |
| Column_5         | CompanyPhoneNumber | Email            |
+------------------+--------------------+------------------+
```